# What is this called in propositional logic?

Tags: logic

What is the common name for something of the form

$\Gamma \vdash B$

where $\Gamma$ is a set of formula and B is a single formula.

I'm currently calling it a conditional assertion. I thought it might be a 'sequent' but I think that is a more general term where there are multiple formulae on the right-hand-side.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols means the basic relation of *derivability* :

> "the formula $B$ is derivable from the set $\Gamma$ of formulae".

See :

- Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA7) (2007), page 7 :

> **Definition 2.1.2** A *sequent* is an expression
>
> > $(\Gamma \vdash \psi)$ (or $\Gamma \vdash \psi$ when there is no ambiguity)
>
> where $\psi$ is a statement (the *conclusion* of the sequent) and $\Gamma$ is a set of statements (the *assumptions* of the sequent). We read the sequent as ‘$\Gamma$ entails $\psi$’. The sequent $(\Gamma \vdash \psi)$ means
>
> > There is a proof whose conclusion is $\psi$ and whose (undischarged) assumptions are all in the set $\Gamma$.